# C# MVC AngularJS

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Code:

```
[ResponseType(typeof(List<MyClass>))] 
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get() 
{ 
    var userId = User.Identity.Name; 
    var obj = await this.FindAllAsync(userId); 

    if (obj == null) 
    { 
        return this.NotFound(); 
    } 

    return this.Ok(obj); 
}
```

It doesn't seem to throw any errors server side however, it does client side in the angular controller does any one have any ideas?

I originally had the code as: ResponseType(typeof(bool)] and now since changing it does not work, so is returning a List object not allowed or do I need to do something extra in either the Angular js file or my C# Controller class to get it to work, e.g. Json-fy it?!?!

Refer to http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/build-a-single-page-application-(spa)-with-aspnet-web-api-and-angularjs for code base. All I have done is change one of calls to return a List I cannot see why this is any different. I have not modified the client side controller class to any significance other than to upgrade the code to the new syntax.

```
$http.get("/api/crosswordHelper").then(
    function (response) {
        //$scope.historyItems = data.userHistory;
        $scope.title = "This app allows you to find all of the words in a dictionary which obey a regular expression.";
        $scope.working = false;
    },
    function (response) {
        $scope.title = "Oops... something went wrong '" + response.statusText + "'";
        $scope.working = false;
    });
```

The application hangs for moment (like 10 seconds) then it shows the "Oops ... " error message with a statusText of 'Internal Server Error'. I can also tell you the call to FindAllSync returns one row as I expect. I do not understand why I need to Json'fy it as sugested in comment below when the original code didn't.

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: ?? How do I display the error. }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.title = "Oops... something went wrong";
                $scope.working = false;
            });

Comment: what codes you have shown not enough to see the problem.you should post angular code and tell us the error details

Comment: need to return json from server

Comment: Sorry being a beginner I am still going around in circles i get a 500 status error. I am using    config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(); in my WebApiConfig Register method i do not really have any idea what this does however more to the point can you direct me to problem on this site that I learn the answer how to Json a List<MyClass> or give me example code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for wasting everybody's time because I found a solution to my own problem - again I get the dummies award. The fact the server was halting every time to render the display that turned the light bulb on for me.

Even though my result set is a list of objects has only 1 item in the list however the object itself contains an internal list of 58,000+ rows!

So I decided only return what I needed for my purposes i.e. I added a [JsonIgnore] tag to the appropriate internal list field of my class as I do not really need this internal list to be brought to the client. Gosh imagine if there was more than one item in my list. Anyhow response is almost simultaneous now!